# Deploy Angular Universal folder Server and Browser

Tags: angular, deployment, server-side-rendering

I've built a project with Angular Universal with the command: npm run build:ssr

Everything worked perfectly as I was able to visualize the result by using npm run serve:ssr

The question is that I have 2 different folders in my "dist" folder:

- Browser: which contains the project
  [image]
- Server: which contains main.js file

I want to deploy the project with ssr on OVH and I don't know which folder I've to send to filezilla.

If I upload the entire dist folder, it doesn't seem to work as the webpage request me to chose the folder I want

If I upload the browser folder I don't have the SSR but the website is working

If I upload the server folder it doesn't seem to work as the webpage requests me to click en the file "main.js" but it's not working.

Do you have a solution ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please tell me if you could find the solution?

Comment: Yes this is actually not possible. Try to use AWS instead: https://medium.com/javarevisited/deploy-angular-universal-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-14dcc44d960b